# Computing algebraic de-Rham cohomology via Čech cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory, homology-cohomology

I have been reading [this paper](http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2012/18-46v.pdf) about de-Rham cohomology  of hyperelliptic curves, and I have been trying to recompute some of what has been done in section 3.

In particular, I am trying to see why the first de-Rham cohomology group is as described.

I have read about (and am relatively happy) with (algebraic) de-Rham cohomology and Čech cohmology seperately, but I seem to be struggling to put them together.

It appears that in the paper the author has taken the cohomology of the total complex of the following square
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[ccc] 
 ~ {\mathcal O}_X(U_1) \times {\mathcal O}_X(U_1) & \rightarrow & \Omega_X(U_1)\times \Omega_X(U_2) \\
\downarrow & ~ & \downarrow \\
{\mathcal O}_X(U_1\cap U_2) & \rightarrow & \Omega_X(U_1\cap U_2)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $X$ is the hyperelliptic curve, $U_1$ and $U_2$ form the cover of $X$ being used (obtained by removing distinct points $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively), and zeroes outside of the diagram.

It seems to me that this is just computing the Čech cohomology of the complex
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[cc]
w0 \rightarrow {\mathcal O}_X \rightarrow \Omega_X \rightarrow 0 && {(1)}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
and I don't see where algebraic de-Rham cohomology is coming in to this.

It appears to me that one would need to take the Čech cohomology of the bicomplex associated to (1) obtained by taking the Godement resolution of $\mathcal O_X$ and $\Omega_X$, but this would give some sort of 3-dimensional complex, and I do not know how to take the cohomology of such a thing.

My guess is that I have some gross misunderstanding, and if anyone could help me with that it would be much appreciated.

Comment: In "nice" cases the de Rham and Cech cohomology are isomorphic: maybe this paper is useful http://www.math.cornell.edu/~bowman/cech.pdf

Comment: To be honest, I do not fully understand the definition at the bottom of p.916, section 3. The author introduces a "mixed" de Rham-$\check{C}ech$ cohomology group; @Joe Tait: is that clear to you?

Comment: @Avitus Thank you for the reference - I had found that when I was trying to understand the problem, but it only appears to deal with "normal" de Rham cohomology, rather than the algebraic, so I am not sure how much it will transfer.
And the part you mention is precisely what I am trying to recreate, as I don't understand it either.

Comment: I am no expert in Kähler differentials, but what I see here is the following. In order to define the space $\check{\mathrm{H}}^1_{dR}(\mathcal U)$ one needs to consider the space of cocycles $\Omega_{X/k}(U_1)\oplus\Omega_{X/k}(U_2)\oplus \mathcal O(U_1\cap U_2)$, s.t. $df=\omega_1-\omega_2$ on $\Omega_{X/k}(U_1\cap U_2)$. My question is: how is $\Omega_{X/k}(\cdot)$ related to deRham diff. forms and $\check{C}ech$-cochains? Is this clear to you?

Comment: I thought that what you described was ${\check{H}}^1(X;{\mathcal O}_X)$ rather than ${\check{H}}^1_{dR}({\mathcal U})$, since you have taken the correct term of total complex of the commutative diagram in the question, and that is just the "normal" Cech complex of the complex (1).

I don't quite know what you mean by de Rham differential forms - do you mean the elements of the de Rham groups? 

I have mostly been working from the note below to understand algebraic de Rham cohomology (continued)

Notes - http://www.math.mcgill.ca/candelori/FallSeminar09-Luca1.pdf

Comment: and so the elements of the de Rham groups would, from those notes, be elements of the Godement resolution of the complex (1) in the question. Finally, I do not know how to relate Cech cochains to this (and I think that is the crux of my problem). Sorry for the very long comments.

Comment: I think my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/q/104741/297 also addresses your question.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Indeed, I had come across that, and it is certainly relevant. I think I had misread it as being an application, rather than a a generalisation, of Leray's theorem. Though it is not entirely clear to me then it looks like I should be able to work it out from your answer and the comments. Thank you for making me read that properly!